# Failure at displaying Bitmaps in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, bitmap, wxwidgets

My application has two Pictures embedded in the Frame. My code is as follows:

```
wxMemoryInputStream istream1(Bild_png, sizeof Bild_png);
wxImage Bild_png(istream1, wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
new wxStaticBitmap(p_img, wxID_ANY, wxBitmap(Bild_png));

vbox->Add(p_img ,0);
```

(vbox is the Sizer)

When I start the App, I've a "T-" at the left-upper corner in both Bitmaps. When I change the `notebookitem("screen")` and get back to the first Screen (where the Bitmaps are) the "-T" has disappeared...

How can I fixed it, so that I will never see the failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to call Layout() at the upmost sizer. That has solved my problem. It means at the end:

```
vbox->Layout()
```

@catalin, I don't think that to post aorund 2000 lines of sourcecode is a better way. I had choose this little snipped, because it says all what needed. A expert with wxWidgets had give me - with this four lines - the hint that something is fault with the sizer, not with the pic.

Answer (score -1):

Haven't you been advised before to search the [samples](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/tree/master/samples)? For example [widgets](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/tree/master/samples/widgets); just grep for `wxStaticBitmap` and I'm sure you'll find something useful.

This is just a poor way of asking a question.
In your c++ snippet you're using `Bild_png` even before it was declared - really? Then you mention `both Bitmaps` and `notebookitem("screen")` which are just unknown items to anyone else but you.
IMO it is just too... wrong to receive a good answer...